# How to separate fields with pipe character delimiter

Tags: bash, sed, awk, pipe, ash

I know this question has already been asked but no of the solution I've found worked for me! I have a program that has an output like this:

```
COUNT|293|1|lps
```

I'm interested in having the second field however no one of these tries worked:

```
./spawn 1 | cut -d '|' -f2
./spawn 1 | cut -d \| -f2
./spawn 1 | awk -F "|" '{print $2}'
./spawn 1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print $2}'
./spawn 1 | sed 's/|/;/g'
./spawn 1 | sed 's/\|/;/g'
```

But the output is always the same:

```
COUNT|293|1|lps
```

Is there a bug somewhere in bash? I would be surprised, the results is the same on my Linux host and on my embedded device using busybox's ash! Any pointer is strongly appreciated!

**EDIT**
My fault, the output was in stderr ... ._.

```
./spawn 1 2>&1 | cut -d '|' -f2
4615
```

Sorry for ennoying!

Comment: Just a guess, but is it possible that `./spawn 1` is printing to standard error instead of standard output?  Does `./spawn 1 2>&1 | cut -d '|' -f2` work, for example?

Answer (score 11):

*Just repeating what I guessed in a comment as an answer, now that the questioner has confirmed that this is the problem.*

The problem here is that `./spawn 1` is outputting to standard error, not standard output.  You can redirect the output using `2>&1`, so the following should work:

```
./spawn 1 2>&1 | cut -d '|' -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo 'COUNT|293|1|lps' | cut -d'|' -f2
293
```

It works here.